# How to merge ScriptResource.axd files in to one file inorder to improve page performance

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, performance-testing

On my website i use Ajax and jQuery along with social media like twitter, Facebook scripts. I noticed that i have many of these file on my asp.net web form application.
While testing my website (with firebug YSlow) for performance I noticed that i have about 13 `ScriptResource.axd` file. Are all of them required or how can i merge them in one to improve performance of the page & how can i can i know if these files are referring to particular ms Ajax control.

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=6GIfwW5NIk8YVdQUBoUSdw8_teFCLpaGZuXT9BltuBtMBUEgJauIENwvz-5lAHOHs7roSmFphXJzKtPwXs4IBi2qKo5Xu9asohZ7zQFIgLxsrV1UVTo2TGF-G5tW5spyJFcooTIB3CmNkKv4pPodTZKjAOM1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=SVRd3p5sxqLRkNZvsASl_qHKNd_EsD7Em0z1kZZKsUc9VUS88b1ehlatIc09u_RZYKinP0KkpUsEIRoWZWC4V4wZCDW1PNIlcAGeQTMCunY5ABoS93xJu4W1URri3RraR6VbuQ2&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=liPBEJshRG6BfJiUI6H1bjejmsntTHSESj5435XDpzn7jyE3zjP5P8pDyWXQPYKGqJyDYemNYEDpOj7eaHhE_TOQimWjTafCcDEPT_-IzPUk98xa9g47-DPKVpM2PbSRDoVVXAjcFdErIMr9oPvCHUd3at41&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=so2-S6sCEWinHjunb1xKM3mqGuiQVUn2N01XLzPdqPR0Zn1x5urYVyz4vejCesXD7qdgPibO0HVa6T7ln_xJ-vgIuDjZGn77Bw51LNHPxM3LNNJvIsdIfVX7H_lY2o1Ld987I-fmlCUDFR6iEiv3_mEJAWs1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=b5bmOM9G88P7EQM94ZrgSDUiVqbpJb90fw5Reep6EoPFByepzn_cWrrvCdRW-fdsjjAeoMp-XZC7F2KEh5i_u_4bCbS9-3byqjW8IOkiQl1mQEBCJmwnEK2DELKgsAaNlpuNlvx6h4CydmlBmkIf8hdTQkA1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=5jy8bTvROjYGk4_2ZP4NEWwvKIpI0oldPhL_Eh6m3GrT6ekBrVTo7-GUSxIX6AD6PC5zSqLy8CN6EuZuPiWdFvsSCam2ki-hwabZoFuSQOLcYwuLOIy_SE7zEe0ytt-m15CycOfApMHv9-RV3sqIMlLd8Xg1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=rmhvV2xwmzqQwS31J44KQbyMR_zRMpUsEAzR2k4zbzQCgANnXCYEh58kTigCaSZ8LT8wrEnzng7fUI8tLzuVwJOyZbmRHqUZZbHk_03U5BHmWNQMhYAEwyVCaAZIeNDVzQIsHHmQ44Soi71NtaKVf6__bFwTaskur12ttbkfE20oCBud0&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=ZNlBs49UYPsWsh1g9g1-3JSj-0tbIQUGbXQP2qwLK1NKGoBKleisjmI-ljano_dkMzL9cyZcEtPSV3Nhres0GcJJTZaM8XQsJWyno5JUrGS0HJsVtsAzlWneSl0XJZp9rdG8zz1palq3F8_Wsj67W1KiUyc1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=bdIISdk0xOnOOnKm5Lg0V3RHL-LtjxpWdqYP2FQFT3I__XsATZOwY_tamhbv9vEnFGuUjIauXgv27hfO3XcF2nXfkzyXjVKY6ouAzcNC7Z9yIKfO5PWbQ8i8CFLxEMO43TCl_VIh8mFv9pYZllMnJC96TLE1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=QZwq1tBmc9srltGXrElP8CgnXBmRsy0QkmV1k7sc16SDweMp3N1RcU7MwtqawWy5tvyiJNg2cDqZ7ijTi1VcWgr8BMTibHYR0uI2ssS0O_OV2FQkh3B6L8557KiFL2aZ8yzJp8IiyCHYmP2rHlthqZ_TsPZKRjCFhDHdWWZVB5BobQMc0&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=m_5nYCrZRv0cBHzoHwFw88IyLI68CfWpjJ_WshaxE3-h39TmNXR9dsYGPJsSAjbXCTy7rqIMgCBJ9asmKjDYA3CZoGMYu0umX80AkS1hxXw23cepeBSLvq0lHlmaWiGP3w5CM6SU_XFJSdOyHG4-H05h3lA1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=t3aTCyZK7M6vzByezVVz_Cs0icKbhxAXxjsT9TQHsWLpMN-bibYGdivH_AqRtO6GZVutz7zUpsy2Aj14_YTFjxra307vqvp5wFDQSEOPF-jF7-lJ7lKtiEQZ_XnrdxT2ws9xXL7Z2L51cQzRqIVWPJ7SMsA1&amp;t=ffffffffc13acc3f" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source module and HTTP Handler that can do this for you -

http://madskristensen.net/post/Optimize-WebResourceaxd-and-ScriptResourceaxd

You might also want to look at CompositeScript and ScriptManager - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx